# Button not showing Material Design

Tags: android, android-layout, anko

**I've found out that the reason is that I'm using the Android-Iconics library - I removed the context injection and everything is fine now.**

I'm using a combination of XML Layouts and Anko DSL to build my app and I've noticed that the button design is different depending on how it's generated.

In case it's an Anko-generated button, the text is in caps (what I think it should be in Material) and has a ripple effect. If the button is created by XML the text is lowercase and without the effect.

[image: Screenshot]

The upper button is the XML one, so here you can see the difference.

I've tried setting a custom style to the button but it doesn't seem to work - I can't even make *textAllCaps=true* work.

Currently I'm using androidx and extending AppCompat & *Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar* and I've tried extending *Widget.AppCompat.Button* to set a custom style to the view without luck.

This is happening in all API levels (24, 26 and 28). In the XML preview it does show fine.

The current XML is

```
<Button
            android:text="@string/compartir"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/debunkShareButton"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/debunkTitle"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            style="@style/Full_Yellow_Button"/>
```

And the *Full_Yellow_Button* is

```
    <style name="Full_Yellow_Button"  parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/yellow_gradient</item>
</style>
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Can you share your XML?

Comment: @Beyazid Yes, sorry - See the updated question.

Comment: @Naroh are you using design support library or new material design library?

Comment: @KaranMer I'm using the new material design library right now, but the same thing happened with the design support library.

Answer (score 1):

Your theme should be extended from `Theme.MaterialComponents.xxxxx`

like this XML block

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

You can create your `TextView` class for set to uppercase

```
class UppercaseTextView : TextView, ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {}

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {}

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle) {}

    override fun setText(text: CharSequence, type: BufferType) {
        super.setText(text.toString().toUpperCase(), type)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've changed to extend Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar and I'm still getting a different design with the text in lowercase. It's happening both using a custom style or without setting one. Screenshot: https://imgur.com/eGHzxUv

Comment: I updated my post, but this textview class cant change to design. It works just for set to uppercase

Answer (score 1):

If you are using new material design components make sure your application theme extends from main theme `Theme.MaterialComponents` or other relavant theme.

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
    <!-- ... -->
</style>
```

Also, instead of using generic `Button` class to define button, You need to use `com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton` in your xml and java both.

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/material_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_label_enabled"/>
```

Comment: Hi Karan, thanks! I've tried extending Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar and using the view com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton but, unlike in the preview, the app keeps showing the button with lowercase letters (and I can't make it uppercase in the XML).

Comment: set `android:textAllCaps="true"` in xml. clean and build your project once changes done.

Comment: Same thing after cleaning and rebuilding the project (textAllCaps was already there). I'm really out of ideas about why is this happening.

Comment: you are extending your button style from `Widget.AppCompat.Button` you should extend it from `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button`

Comment: I've found out that the reason is that I'm using the Android-Iconics library - I removed the context injection and everything is fine now.